# Interpreting NetworkX circular graphs

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have created the following graph using NetworkX in Python. I have two related questions.

[NetworkX graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxPG5.png)

1. What determine the edges' lengths and the lengths of the thick parts of the edges?
2. I would like either the length of the thick part of the edges or the length of the edges to represent the weights I assigned to each edge. It is not the case in this graph, even though each edge has the wanted weight (when I check using G.get_edge_data()). How to represent these weights on the graph?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lengths of the "arrowheads" is set to be 25% of the line width (from node center to node center).  This appears to be hardcoded in so it cannot be changed.

Instead, you can use the keyword "width" (see the [documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html?highlight=draw_networkx_edge)) combined with an "edgelist" so that it knows which edge gets which width.

> width : float, or array of floats Line width of edges (default=1.0)

Comment: Thank you, it looks much better. Is there a way to make these "arrowheads" look more like arrows? (Since it seems like they only serve to indicate directions.) I did not find anything in the documentation.
(Should I ask this follow-up question in another separate post?)

Comment: Not really.  The documentation says: "For directed graphs, “arrows” (actually just thicker stubs) are drawn at the head end. Arrows can be turned off with keyword arrows=False. Yes, it is ugly but drawing proper arrows with Matplotlib this way is tricky."  I think the challenge is that as it is the arrow goes from center of node to center of node.  Making an arrowhead that isn't covered by the node requires adjusting for the diameter of the node.  This is tricky.